# How can I print HTML code with colors syntax highlighting on my HTML page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm trying to converts my code snippets into pretty-printed HTML format with syntax highlighting.

```
            <xmp ng-non-bindable>
                <ul>
                    <li ng-repeat="list in lists" class="input">
                        {{list}}
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </xmp>
```

---

**Result**

[image]

---

**I want to print out something like this**

[image]

---

What is the best day to achieve something like that ?

Can someone please direct me to the right direction ?

Comment: have a look at [highlightjs](https://highlightjs.org/).

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using [highlightjs](https://highlightjs.org/) as it supports a large number of languages and comes with many color themes. For HTML code specifically, you need to escape HTML tags. There're many tools online to help you in achieving that.

[Here's](https://jsfiddle.net/njhf51us/embedded/result/) a quick demo for that using highlighjs:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/8.6/styles/darkula.min.css">
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/8.6/highlight.min.js"></script>
<script>hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();</script>
<pre><code class="hljs html">
&lt;ul&gt;
&lt;li ng-repeat=&quot;list in lists&quot; class=&quot;input&quot;&gt;
{{list}}
&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;/ul&gt;
</code></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

To print your HTML tags,manually you need to replace the < with `&lt;` and > with `&lgt;`

So if your code is this,then you can print the tags.

```
  &lt;xmp ng-non-bindable&gt;<br />
                &lt;ul&gt;<br />
                    &lt;li ng-repeat=&quot;list in lists&quot; class=&quot;input&quot;&gt;<br />
                        {{list}}<br />
                    &lt;/li&gt;<br />
                &lt;/ul&gt;<br />
            &lt;/xmp&gt;
```

A better way would be to use the following
and Try this Syntax highlighter [link](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/)

Comment: thank-you @Varun, but please keep suggesting guys I want to know more about this.

Comment: @开发人员 Please see the edit i have made,this way you can do it manually too.

Comment: With all the respects, I appreciated that you're trying to show me how to do it manually, but I think it just make the code look horrible. I guess, I 'll just keep looking for better way of doing it.

Comment: @开发人员 Yes,that's true,manually thats the way,other method may be to get the html code in a JS string,and use string handling to replace the < and > ,but the best would be to use a plugin.

Comment: you have a small error in this response. Use `&gt;` instead of `&lgt;`

Answer (score 0):

you could use a function to programatically escape the html content.

```
function escapeHTML(htmlStr) {
  return htmlStr.split("<").join("&lt;").split(">").join("&gt;");
}
```

Also you could store the content of the snippet in a file, fetch it and inject it programatically with JS:

```js
// fetch the file to get its content as string
fetch("full/path/to/file")
  .then(response => response.text()) // process response
  .then(text => {
    // escape HTML
    const escapedHTML = escapeHTML(text);
    
    // get target DOM element (code element)
    // and inject snippet content
    const snippetEl = document.querySelector("#mySnippet")
    snippetEl.innerHTML = escapedHTML;
    
    // reapply highlighting
    hljs.highlightBlock(snippetEl);
  })
```